# Android Widget Customization

Tags: android-widget, widget

I want to put my widget on lock screen of android phone.

I have created widget with one button. I want to put that widget on lock screen of my phone.

How can i do this?

Please give me proper suggestions.

Thanks,
Jay Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create your own home screen then disable the lock screen and use your home screen as your lock screen. I don't think there is any facility in android that allow programmer to customize the lock screen.